# Decoding program in Java

Tags: java

Thanks for the help guys. Looked into arrays. Think I have it, but I'm having a hard time with getting it to print out. Any ideas? It prints out the word test, but only after several spaces (assuming thats where my letters are supposed to show up) Came up with this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[] aArray = new char[10];
    String[] Acypher = { "D", "D", "W", "E", "L", "H", "O", "R" };

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        int input = in.nextInt();
        switch (input) {
        case 1:
            String newin1 = Acypher[1];
            break;
        case 2:
            String newin2 = Acypher[2];
            break;
        case 3:
            String newin3 = Acypher[3];
            break;
        case 4:
            String newin4 = Acypher[4];
            break;
        case 5:
            String newin5 = Acypher[5];
            break;
        case 6:
            String newin6 = Acypher[6];
            break;
        case 7:
            String newin7 = Acypher[7];
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Translation unknown. Please enter a new number.");
            --i;
            break;

        }
    }
    String aArrayDc = new String(aArray);
    System.out.println(aArrayDc + "test");
}
}
```

Comment: Why you have two: numInputs++;

Comment: I would suggest googling the following: arrays (to store the input in), in.HasNext() (to read in from the scanner), and switch statements (to decode).

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution, but next time do your homework without asking for the solution

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class q1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] cipher = { 'D', 'W', 'E', 'L', 'H', 'O', 'R' };
        char decoded[] = new char[10];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            int num;
            do {
                num = in.nextInt();
            } while (num < 1 || num > 7);
            decoded[i] = cipher[num - 1];
        }
        System.out.println(decoded);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know its homework? Did he write that somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to rewrite your iterations to a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int input = in.nextInt();
    //switch statement
}
```

You need to use a switch statement to find the letter for each number, we add a default case to handle an incorrect number.
This switch goes in the for loop.

```
switch(input)
{
    case 1:
        //store letter to array
        break;
    ...
    default:
        --i;
        System.out.println("Incorrect number, please enter a new number");
}
```

To store the letter of each match, we create an array, we already know it needs a length of 10.
This line goes before the for loop:

```
char[] decodedCharacters = new char[10]
```

Put this one in each switch statement:

```
decodedCharacters[i] = "D"; //another letter for each case.
```

And this one is to print all characters:

```
String decodedString = new String(decodedCharacters);
System.out.println(decodedString);
```

EDIT:
See @Guillaume 's answer for an approach leaving more flexibility for other combinations.
His answer doesn't handle an incorrect number though.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Just got a chance to sit down and hopefully got it, but ran into a problem printing it out. Can you take a look and see if there's anything wrong with it? New code is in original post.

Comment: You're writing each letter to a variable `newin1` but you're actually not doing anything with it. Just replace any occurrence of `newin1` and so on with `aArray[i]` :)

Comment: You might also want to catch the exception thrown when something else than an `int` is entered.